# Google Smart Home: "is <light> <state>? doesn't do a QUERY

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

Everytime I do a: “Is {light} ON?”, Google Home doesn’t do a QUERY against our integration. It always use the cached result from ReportState.

Even with ReportState sending “online”: false, the response is "The {light} is " instead of {light} isn't available right now".

Here is an example of our Report State:

```
{  
    "requestId":"fecfa392-5bdc-4054-bc70-e4499bc4a733”, 
    "agent_user_id":"2”, 
    "payload":{  
        "devices":{  
            "states":{  
                "60dcd8a06472":{  
                    "online":false,
                    "color":{  
                        "spectrumRGB":16711680
                    },
                    "on":false,
                    "brightness":0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Google Home Graph API respond with success and if we play with this and ask: “Is {light} ON?”, the response from Google match the latest ReportState but the online: false is always ignored.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in how the responses are being handled, as if the device is offline that should take precedence. But pulling the state from the home graph directly should be working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Google Home depends on a variety of factors in order to provide state responses to users including Query, Report State and a combination of these. In order to ensure a good experience, you need to implement both correctly.

The `offline:false` case takes precedence now, given it was done as your most recent reported state and does not include any other values (When you do report a device is offline, do not report other trait values or attributes). If you still get a different behavior, you can report it on the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).